# How long can a flat tire sit before the sidewall is ruined?

Tags: tires, tire-pressure

I'm on business and two days ago my wife noticed that one of our cars has a flat. She can probably take care of it tomorrow, but that means that the tire will have sat, completely flat for the better part of three days. She hasn't driven on it.

Is my sidewall ruined? I don't want to do anything unsafe, but if we can get the tire patched, that would be quite preferable...

Wanted some informed opinions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tire shop should be able to give you the definitive word, but I'd not have an issue patching it and putting it back out on the road. As long as you don't see any dry rot occurring (cracks along the super flexed portions of where the flat is at) you really shouldn't have anything to worry about especially seeing as how it hasn't been driven on. A couple of days flat should not cause an issue.

Comment: Awesome! Tires are about 2 1/2 years old, fair amount of tread left. Wife must have hit a nail. Really appreciate the opinion!